# Transform on Material UI Icon showing "Invalid property value" (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

Trying to get an Icon styled properly from Material UI to flip 180 degrees, CSS code is as follows:

```
sortIconDescending: {
    transform: [{ rotate: "180deg"}],
    cursor: 'pointer',
    marginLeft: 5,
},
```

For some reason when this class is applied on the icon, it denies the applied `transform` property:

```
><!> ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶f̶o̶r̶m̶:̶ ̶[̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶O̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶]̶;̶ - Err: Invalid property value
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try transform:{rotate:'180deg'}

Comment: @Near, yes unfortunately it doesn't work. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

I found a valid solution, instead of applying the `transform:` property value as a array containing an object `[{rotate: "180deg"}]`, you would just write the following code:

```
sortIconDescending: {
    transform: "rotate(180deg)",
    cursor: 'pointer',
    marginLeft: 5,
},
```

This seems to be the best solution.